# What Does the Switch in 'The Construction Site' Do?

Tags: bionic-commando-rearmed

[image: The Bionic Arm Switch]

I almost missed it, but this box is one of the switches like you see in the first tutorial level.  I hit it with my bionic arm, and there was a satisfying *clunk*, but I have no idea what it did.  Did it change something waaaay back down at the bottom of the level?

Comment: I can't remember if that is related to the Yashaishi in that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It opens this door:

Inside you can get

> the Secret Challenge Room 5