# Where is the Yashichi in the Construction Yard?

Tags: bionic-commando-rearmed

[image: Secret Door]

I'm still missing a 'secret' in this stage, which has to be the 'Yashichi' as there's one in each level.  I've scoured the level top to bottom, and the only suspicious thing left appears to be this door to the left of the boss fight area.  There doesn't appear to be any way to reach it.  How do I open it, and then how do I *get* to it to explore the secrets within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get to this door, and it's not where the Yashichi is.

The Yashichi is earler in the level, there's a good walkthrough in [this guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/900/900189p1.html):

> [From the start of the level] walk all the way right until you encounter a concrete block that you
>    can't climb over. Walk back a little bit and start climbing up until you 
>    reach the small building with a picture of a hard hat on it. Get on top
>    of that building. You want to swing from the point on the roof above
>    the small building that is just under a blue barrel. Make a couple of
>    swings until you're under the blue barrel and then swing right to land
>    on the concrete block. The Yashichi is just past it.

Comment: Then... this means you can't reach the door in the boss area.  The switch outside the entrance to the boss fight opens a completely different door back in the main level.  [See Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39472/what-does-the-switch-in-the-construction-site-do).  At any rate, the first part of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, two doors behind sandbags in that level, didn't realize.  Answer updated.